# Change DataGridView Font Color of a specific field

Tags: vb.net, colors, datagridview, row, cell

In vb.net, how can I change the Color of a specific field in DataGridView?

I can change the value like this:

```
Guna2DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value = "Hello"
```

But..

1. No changes from this:

```
Guna2DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Style.ForeColor = Color.Lime
```

2. DefaultCellStyle doesn't work here:

```
guna2datagridview.Rows(0).Cells(2).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Lime
```

Comment: Which events fire those codes ?

Comment: Nevermind, it's working now, I have no idea why it wasn't working for me earlier.. Sorry

Needed it for "Timer1_Tick" and the solution is:
DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Style.ForeColor = Color.Lime